# Making a spring 5 skinny war compatible with Jboss wildfly

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, wildfly, maven-3

I've been trying to create a skinny WAR which would allow me to extract all the common jars to a wildfly module. This is because 70MB WAR's are becoming unsustainable in daily operations.

My approach was:

1. Create a wildfly module (by hand) with all the Jars, except my own libraries and spring-web.jar.
2. Modified my war project pom.xml adding this: (where mystuff-*.jar are our own libraries of the project)

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       </manifest>
               </archive>
               <packagingExcludes>
                   %regex[WEB-INF/lib/(?!spring-web|mystuff-).*.jar]
               </packagingExcludes>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. Added a jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the following:

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
       <deployment>
           <dependencies>
               <module name="my-company.core-libs" />
           </dependencies>
       </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```

Now this has two issues: first, I'm getting the "No Spring WebApplicationInitialized types detected on classpath, so the applicatio does not start at all.

Secondly, a toon of "Class Path entry spring-tx-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar in */wildfly_root/bin/content/spring-tx-5.1.3-relase.jar* does not point to a valid jar for a class-path reference" messages. (this is an example, a spring-boot app has 70MB of jars and all of them give this warning).

Checking the manifest I see a lot of jars under Class-Path which appear to be OK.

How can I fix this? Surely there must be a way to force wildfly to find my SpringBootServletInitializer class and start the app.

Btw, I tried some options on the maven-war-plugin and the one above is (so far) the only one that allows Eclipe to deploy directly to the server.

Stack:

- Wildfly 15
- Spring 5.1.3 with spring-boot.
- Latest maven and eclipse.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried http://ibrahimsawalha.blogspot.com/2017/11/add-spring-4-as-jboss-module-in-wildfly.html . You have to mention all the spring dependencies in the module.xml too. If your project is open source I would love to try that :-)

Comment: I tried, but still a lot of errors caused by classes not being visible by the class loader, for example: javax.validation.Validator referenced from a method is not visible from class loader